# Is possible run window application without message loop

Tags: c, windows, winapi, message-queue

I have a very old application and I'm surprised. This application runs without message loop.
(**GetMessage** or **PeekMessage**).

How is it possible?

Edited example from Visual Studio:

```
HINSTANCE g_hInstance = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);

ATOM _RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    _RegisterClass(hInstance);

    InitInstance(hInstance, SW_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

ATOM _RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXA wcex = {0};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_SAVEBITS;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = "TEST_CLASS";

    ATOM a = 0;

    a =  RegisterClassExA(&wcex);

    return a;
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    g_hInstance = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    hWnd = CreateWindowA("TEST_CLASS", "TEST_WINDOW", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

     SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_USER, 111, 0);

    return TRUE;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        OutputDebugStringA("Create called.\n");
        break;

case WM_USER:
    {
        if (wParam == 111)
        {

            OutputDebugStringA("User called.\n");
        }
    }
            break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        OutputDebugStringA("Destroy called.\n");
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

DEBUG OUTPUT:

Create called.
User called.
Destroy called.
The program '[2152] Test.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Does the application create a window?

Comment: Yes of course create the window.

Comment: In what language is it written? What frameworks does it use? How does it create its main window?

Comment: It's not possible, you just haven't found out how it does it yet. Either that or it's a DOS app and you're mistaking a command window for a Windows window.

Comment: It runs and finishes without showing a window. There is no message processing that I can see. `WM_CREATE` gets passed to your `WindowProc` as a result of `CreateWindow` but that doesn't mean you've got a message loop.

Comment: And WM_CREATE is not message?

Comment: I'm not _that_ into Win32, but this code seems to instruct Windows to use your [`WindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx), causing the callback to be called for every message instead of translating and dispatching it in your own message loop.

Comment: What kind of callback do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is expected behavior.

`CreateWindow` calls `SendMessage` to send `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE` to the window being created. `SendMessage` behaves as follows (quote from MSDN):

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine.

Your program calls `CreateWindow`, which subsequently calls your window procedure (outputting "Create called" upon `WM_CREATE`) and then returns. It verifies that the window handle is non-null, which is the case, and returns with an exit code of 0 instead of entering a message pump.
It does not output "Destroy called" (as you maybe expected) because that isn't happening. The window is not being destroyed (well, *eventually it is*, by the operating system), the program just exits.

**About the edited code:**
The new code differs in calling `SendMessageW`, which again calls the window procedure directly. Therefore, the user message is received although there is no message pump.
It seems like the destroy message now makes it through, too, which is admittedly a bit surprising. Not sure what the reason for that would be.

Note that the window was created with an "A" function, so calling a "W" function is generally not advisable (even though it seems to "work" here).

Comment: Interesting, see my edited example, still no loop, so how is WM_USER delivered?

Comment: > how is WM_USER delivered? ; You're sending the message directly. Try to post the message with `PostMessage`, and you'll see the message won't be received.